# Wy is my form submit event listener is not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form and I am trying to listen to the event when the user submits the form. Here are my codes:

html:

```js
    const form = document.forms['testRegForm']
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    alert("Test");
                    var x = document.forms["required"]["mobile"].value;
                    if (x == "") {
                        alert("Mobile Number is required");
                        return false;
                    }else {
                        alert(x)
                        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
                        .then(response => 
                            alert('Your request is submitted. We will get in touch with you soon')
                        )
                        .catch(error => alert(error.message))
                    }
                    
                })
```

```html
     <form name="testRegForm" style="font-family: Aladin;" >
                    <p>Register using mobile Number: </p>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Number" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" name="mobile" maxlength="10" required><br><br>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    <p></p>
     </form>
```

But the event listener does not work when the submit button is clicked. This is verified by the fact that the alert - "Test" is not shown. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The alert does fire (even with `document.forms['testRegForm']`) so long as the validation on the Number field passes.   The `pattern` attribute will prevent submit from firing until it matches the input successfully.

Comment: I checked by removing the pattern in my localhost Chrome and Safari. But still the alert did not fire. Not sure If I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: It fires in the snippet above, so I'm not sure what's happening on your end of things.   (As Scott Marcus points out below, the selector for your `var x` is incorrect, but the submit handler itself is working fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event is indeed firing, it just doesn't complete because of an error referencing the `input`. Also, make sure that the `script` is located just before the closing `body` tag so that the HTML will be fully parsed by the time the `script` is encountered.

Replace `const form = document.forms['testRegForm']` with `const form = document.querySelector("form")` and modify your reference to the `input` as with a valid selector as shown below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="testRegForm" style="font-family: Aladin;" >
    <p>Register using mobile Number: </p>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Number" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" name="mobile" maxlength="10" required><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <p></p>
</form>

<script>
// A standard API for locating a DOM element is .querySelector()
// which takes any valid CSS selector:
const form = document.querySelector("form");

// Get your DOM references that you'll work with more than once
// only once, so this has been moved outside of the event callback.
// Also, "mobile" isn't an attribute, so your selector wasn't working
// for it. And, it's best to get references to DOM elements, rather
// than a particular property of an element so that if you decide you
// want a difference property value, you've already got the element
// reference and won't need to scan for it again.
var x = document.querySelector("[required][name='mobile']");
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("Test");

   if (x.value == "") {
      alert("Mobile Number is required");
      return false;
   }else {
      alert(x.value);
      fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
         .then(response => 
             alert('Your request is submitted. We will get in touch with you soon')
         ).catch(error => alert(error.message))
   }
});
</script>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't necessary. document.forms is a valid (if somewhat old-fashioned) way to access the form element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

Comment: @DanielBeck See updated answer. But, while `document.forms()` still works, I strongly advise against it as it just fosters more out of date solutions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You're answer has nothing to do with the OP's question about the event not firing. The event does fire, even with the OP's outdated form selection if the number entered is valid. Daniel pointed that out in his comment under the OP's post

Comment: @ScottMarcus No. It didn't. There is no issue. The event fires if the number is entered correctly. Tested it in the OP's code sample

Comment: @ScottMarcus Because your answer has nothing to do with the event not firing. The event does fire. You just updated your answer to reflect what Daniel pointed out.

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, that's the point. The answer has been updated to be more comprehensive, yet you are still arguing that it doesn't address the question.

Comment: Edit #5 now actually addresses the question that was asked (though I don't love that it still implies that the form selector was incorrect). downvote removed

Comment: document.forms is part of the HTML living standard.    Your answer currently falsely implies that a perfectly valid, standards-based, (and performant, and "easy") method is incorrect.  (In fact the original version is better in that it specifies a specific form; your current suggestion will match the first form element in the page, which may or may not be the intended one.)

Comment: @DanielBeck It is in the WHATWG standard, but is obsolete in the W3C standard (which is the more prevalent one). And while I may have passed a generic selector that matches the first form element in my example, that in no way translates to `document.forms[index]` being a better approach as I could just as easily passed a different selector to `.querySelector()`.

Comment: You could have!  One might even say you *should* have.